# How to drop and create tables on SORM?

Tags: scala, sorm

In order to make isolated tests, it would be interesting to drop and create tables or clean them before each test. Any easy way to do it with SORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new instances for each test with `initMode` set to [DropAllCreate](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#initialization_mode) and free all instance's resources after, using the [close()](http://sorm-framework.org/api/#sorm.Instance) method.

A custom function like the following might be helpful to you:

```
def withDb ( f : Instance => () ) {
  val db = new Instance ( ..., initMode = InitMode.DropAllCreate )
  f(db)
  db.close()
}
```

Using it it'll be easy to always work in a context of a freshly created instance:

```
withDb { db =>
  db.save(...)
  db.query[...](...)
}
```

Comment: Would be cool to have a clear method to drop and reload the tables without establishing the connection again...

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to define the reload method to drop and recreate tables without reconnecting. My Instance definition:

```
class DatabaseTest extends Instance(...) {
  def reload = {
    connector.withConnection { connection =>
      connection.dropAllTables()
      Create.tables(mappings.values).foreach {
        t => connection.createTable(t)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. But still we won't rush with including such low-level functionality in the API yet. At least until a decent feedback comes in.

Comment: We could think about a "test-kit" API and this would be available. Thank you for the fast feedback.

Comment: A single function is not enough for a kit, and I don't see much requirement for other functions yet. Again, we need more feedback.